# Trying to parse JSON in swift with swiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

The issue is i am not able to populate an array with what I thought would be correct code to parse a JSON file with swiftyJSON.

As well as I am not sure if the process at which i send the request is correct.

JSON format: this should be simplified to what it truly represents: A dictionary with a "string" key and value of an array of dictionaries. then a string key with a value of a dictionary. then a string with a value of a string which i need.

```
 { 
    "string1" : [
       { "string2" : {
            "string3" : "DataINeed" 
          }
        }
     ]
  }
```

my code

```
func downloadSecondJSONData(completed: DownloadComplete)
{

    let API_ServerKey = "My API Key"
    let URL_Search = "URL Address"

    let urlString = "\(URL_Search)"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!

    Alamofire.request(.GET,url).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
        switch response.result
        {
        case .Success:
            if let value = response.result.value
            {
                let json = JSON(value)
                if let data = json["string1"]["string2"]["string3"].string
                {
                    self.dataArray.append(data)
                }

            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
        completed()
    }

}

func printData()
{
    print(self.dataArray.count)

}
```

How I am attempting to call the methods

```
downloadFirstJSONData { () -> () in
        self.randomMethod() //data i use with the downloadFirstJSONData is required to use in the downloadSecondJSONData

        self.downloadSecondJSONData({ () -> () in
            self.printData() //check if data has been stored
        })

    }
```

Comment: `json["string1"][0]["string2"]["string3"].string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're not accessing the array after the first dictionary.

I guess the safe way to access the first object would be:

```
if let array = json["string1"].array,
    let firstDict = array.first,
    let data = firstDict["string2"]["string3"].string {
        self.dataArray.append(data)
}
```

But I suppose with SwiftyJSON you can also do a variation of what you had:

```
if let data = json["string1"][0]["string2"]["string3"].string {
    self.dataArray.append(data)
}
```

Comment: fantastic. was able to access fine with the second method you had posted. just forgot that i need to identify which index of the array i was accessing